# Creating and persisting a new User based on html input. Spring MVC, JPA Hibernate, Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Searched all over the Internet and tryed different solutions, but somehow no one worked in my case.

I have following html template for a view where you should register yourself:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
    <!-- Page title -->
    <title> Register</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="#" th:action="@{/registeruser}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" />
    <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" />
    <input type="text" th:field="*{password}" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

also here is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

     @Autowired
    private UserService userservice;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String regUser(Model model) {
        User u = new User();
        u.setUsername("username");
        u.setPassword("password");
        u.setEmail("email");
        Set<Role> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.add(roleService.findRoleByName("ROLE_USER"));
        u.setRoles(userRoles);

        System.out.println("test");

        model.addAttribute("user", u);
        return "register";
      //  return new ModelAndView("register", "command", new User());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registeruser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addUser(@ModelAttribute(value = "user")User user,
                ModelMap model) {

            model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("password", user.getPassword());
        model.addAttribute("email", user.getEmail());

        System.out.println("user " + user.getUsername() + "got registered, here a list of all users: " );
        return "login";
    }
}
```

The console print test works in the regUser() method but somehow the console print in the addUser() method does not work, so I guess it does not get triggered? 
Also the View works perfect and I get redirected after submitting to the login page, but this is also the defaultSuccesFulUrl so it probably means nothing.

Kinda frustrated on this one, so it would be really nice if you could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing `action="#"`

Comment: removed it, behaviour did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `action="#"` in your form.  This may be stepping on the one that's generated through Thymeleaf.

Aside:

- You can use `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` as shorthand for your
  mappings.
- You'll want to change it to `input type="password"`
- You can use `Model` instead of `ModelMap`
- Use `@Slf4j` and a logging system of your choice

Comment: thanks for those advices, removing the "action = "#"" statement did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your POST method to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registeruser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(User user) {
...
```

Also is better if in your submit, says is a button

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

And as said *bphlilipnyc* remove the action="#"